# Chinese Remainder Theorem determining kernel of projection

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question on the use of the chinese remainder theorem with regards to a ring isomorphism.

Suppose R is a ring and R = $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-3x +2)$.

Then note that $(x^2 - 3x + 2) = (x - 1)(x-2)$. Set $I = (x-1)$ and $J = (x-2)$.

Now I + J = $\mathbb{R}[x]$, so $IJ$ = $I$ $\bigcap$ $J$.

Then we have the homomorphism $\phi$: $\mathbb{R}[x]$ -> ($\mathbb{R}[x]$ mod $I$, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ mod $J$) via the canonical projection.

Then the kernel of $\phi$ is I $\bigcap$ J, however I'm having trouble concluding that the kernel equals $(x-1)(x-2)$. I realize when $I$ and $J$ are comaximal that IJ = I $\bigcap$ J. But $IJ$ is not simply the product of (x-1) and (x-2). It is the set of all sums of products of elements in I and J.

Why is it that we can conclude $I$ $\bigcap$ $J$ = $(x-1)(x-2)$?

Thanks!

Comment: If you take *any* product of an element of $I$ and an element of $J$, isn't it a polynomial times $(x-1)(x-2)$?

Comment: yes it is, so are u saying when we compute all sums of products of elements of I and J, we can just factor out an (x-1)(x-2) and the result is (x-1)(x-2)f(x)?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I'm saying :)

Comment: but in general, IJ need not be an ideal, what condition can we put on I and J (or our ring) to insure IJ is an ideal? would a possible condition be that I and J are both principle?

Comment: I don't understand. First of all, it's *principal*, not *principle*. More seriously, $IJ$ is defined as you stated precisely so that it *will* be an ideal. Are you asking when you can drop the "sum of all ..." from the actual definition?

Comment: yes, that is what I am asking

Comment: Yes, then you certainly need principal ideals. If you need $2$ or more elements to generate an ideal, then you will need two or more terms in the sum to get closure under sum.